# Reducing memory consumption of Plotly graphs with Dash

Tags: python, web, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am using Dash and have Plotly to display 3D-mesh diagrams, sometimes having necessary to show 5 diagrams at the same time.

This causes a lot of memory build-up when I inspect the webpage and I believe is slowing things down a lot in my webapp.

Any advice for how to reduce memory consumption by Plotly graphs in Dash?

I was thinking maybe we could combine the meshes somehow, or would not help with memory reduction?

Comment: show each on a separate page with links to each. Or load each sequentially when clicked on.

Comment: how many data points are you passing to the mesh diagrams?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you gave more details and images showing what you're talking about but it's possible that you're plots have more data points than needed. Perhaps you could use a sample of the data points instead of all of them in order to help it run faster; e.g., reduce 1,000,000 data points to 1,000 and still get basically the same plot.